# String from mobx store used as a react component name?

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

Using a map feels a bit repetative.

Any way to render react component using string passed down from mobx?
because when i have like 20 different dynamic components its quickly getting messy and repetative.

currently I'm using:

```
function ParentComponent(){
  const compNames = {
      component1: <component1/>,
      component2: <component2/>,
  }
  const component = compNames[store.name];
  return( 
        <div>
            <MyComponentName type={type}/>
        </div>
   )
}
```

is anything shorter possible? for example

```
function ParentComponent(){
  const {name: MyComponentName, type } = store
  return(
    <div>
        <MyComponentName type={type}/>
    </div>
  )
}
```

the Parent component then imported into the index page.

Comment: It's not very clear what you are asking. Could you elaborate a bit? [What you have written works](https://codesandbox.io/s/017j2xpz5w).

Answer (score 0):

```
// MobX store
import UserList from "./UserList";
import UserView from "./UserView";

@observable
component = {
    "user-list": UserList,
    "user-view": UserView
};


// observer component
@observer function UserComponent({type}) {
    const Component = store.component[type];

    return <Component />;
}


// display the component
<UserComponent type="user-list" />
```